# Using grep with regular expression

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

The command `grep -vf 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt` puts in `3.txt` what `2.txt` has that `1.txt` doesn't have, but how can I use `grep` to only to compare the strings that have (0-9)?

```
Example:

(0001) compare  
test   ignore  
984    ignore  
(10)   compare  
(1242342542) compare
```

Comment: So you wish the final output to only contain the pattern, or use only use lines with that pattern for the comparison?

Comment: Do you want to compare two files, but `(0001) compare` in `1.txt` should match `(10) compare` in `2.txt`?

Comment: Any particular reason you have to use grep? I'm not sure _exactly_ what you're trying to do but it sounds like awk would be a better fit. Posting some sample input and expected output would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy way would be:

before saving to 3.txt, pipe your result to `grep -E '[0-9]+' > 3.txt`

looks like:
`grep -vf.... |grep -E '[0-9]+' > 3.txt`

if you give some example of 1.txt , 2.txt and expected 3.txt, there might be an efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep only results that match the pattern, you can simply post-process the output:

```
grep -vf 1.txt 2.txt | grep '([0-9]\+)' > 3.txt
```

Or, if you wish to use only lines from `1.txt` that matches the pattern for the comparison, you could try:

```
grep -vf <(grep "([0-9]\+)" 1.txt) 2.txt > 3.txt
```

Comment: Shawn, Lev thanks for your replies. This is exactly what I want:  grep -vf 1.txt 2.txt | grep '([0-9]\+)' > 3.txt  ... But I'm not getting all the expected results [ (00001) for example is not working ]. The idea is all strings from (0000) to (9999)

Comment: If you want to limit your pattern to 4 digits, i.e. (0000) to (9999), try `grep -E "\([0-9]{4}\)"`

Comment: Shawn i believe it's not working. 1.txt ( (1) aaa, test, (03) test ) ... 2.txt ( (0003) bla, test3, (1111) ble ) ... With that regular expression file 3.txt stays empty, when it should have (0003) bla and (1111) ble ... Please note that the contents of txt files are on separate lines

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your requirements. Can you post example inputs (for `1.txt` and `2.txt`) and the output you expect?

Comment: 1.txt has abc, (0001) def, ghi .. 2.txt has jkl, (0001) def, (0007) xyz ... I want 3.txt to have ONLY (0007) xyz because it has ([0-9]) and it's not present in 1.txt

Comment: Actually grep -vf 1.txt 2.txt | grep '([0-9]\+)' > 3.txt is working :) thank you very much for your support

Comment: OK. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$0];next} !($1 in arr)' 1.txt 2.txt
```

regards